# Cosmos DB Mocking for Azure Functions

Tags: nosql, azure-functions, azure-cosmosdb

I'm new to CosmosDB and azure functions and have no idea how it works.

Anyway a project I'm working on is using CosmosDB. They have created some azure functions to insert and get data in/out from Cosmos DB. I have to tests these function by mocking the Cosmos DB in my local machine.

How can I test these methods? How to mock Cosmos DB in my local machine?

Comment: Usually when you install the SDK in Visual Studio it gives you access to the Emulator on your local machine, can I confirm you've installed those?

Comment: @Captain_Custard Yes it's insatlled.

Comment: The CosmosDB emulator should be installed alongside that then?

Comment: @Captain_Custard It is installed. I want to know how to configure it, write the test cases and how to run it inside the emulator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have already installed Cosmos DB Emulator, you could operate documents in Cosmos DB locally with [SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/create-sql-api-dotnet) or on the data explorer directly.

Sample Insert Document Code:

```
using Microsoft.Azure.Documents;
using Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Client;
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace JayGongDocumentDB.module
{
    class TestEmulator
    {
        private static readonly string endpointUrl = "https://localhost:8081";
        private static readonly string authorizationKey = "C2y6yDjf5/R+ob0N8A7Cgv30VRDJIWEHLM+4QDU5DE2nQ9nDuVTqobD4b8mGGyPMbIZnqyMsEcaGQy67XIw/Jw==";
        private static readonly string databaseId = "db";
        private static readonly string collectionId = "coll";

        private static DocumentClient client;

        public static async Task TestAsync()

        {
            client = new DocumentClient(new Uri(endpointUrl), authorizationKey);
            var uri = UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri(databaseId, collectionId);

            var doc = new Document();
            doc.SetPropertyValue("name", "jay");

            await client.CreateDocumentAsync (
                "/dbs/db/colls/coll", doc,null);
            Console.WriteLine("insert success");

        }
    }
}
```

You could find the endpointUrl and key in azure cosmos db emulator:

[image]

About azure function, you could follow the [official doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-cosmos-db-triggered-function) to create Cosmos DB Trigger Azure Function.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Microsoft.Azure.Documents;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host;

namespace TestAzureFunction
{
    public static class Function1
    {
        [FunctionName("Function1")]
        public static void Run([CosmosDBTrigger(
            databaseName: "db",
            collectionName: "coll",
            ConnectionStringSetting = "CosmosdbString",
            LeaseCollectionName = "leases")]IReadOnlyList<Document> input, TraceWriter log)
        {
            if (input != null && input.Count > 0)
            {
                log.Verbose("Documents modified " + input.Count);
                log.Verbose("First document Id " + input[0].Id);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Hope it helps you.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I just had the time to go through it. Hopes it helps. Get back to you if need any clarifications.

Comment: @Pegasus Sure.waiting for your reply.

Comment: Your answer helped me a lot. Thank you so much.